# How do I make a result in same page laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, api

now i create api and done success

but i get result in white page like that

screen : https://i.ibb.co/H2GyFQ8/stylex.png

so how can get result in same page and with modal

Controller

```
   public function requestReport()
    {
        $pageTitle = 'Checker IMEI Services';
        
        return view('admin.reports',compact('pageTitle'));
        
    }

  public function imeiSubmit(Request $request)
    {
        
     $format = "html"; // Display result in JSON or HTML format
     $imei = $_POST['imei']; // IMEI or SERIAL Number
     $apiKey ='EJwka-pKEL9-1Ctnc-iLn67-NWF77-cqkhT';
     $service = $_POST['service']; // Service ID
     
     if(!filter_var($imei, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
         $imei = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $imei);
     }
     if($service != 'demo') {
      $service = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "", $service);
     }
     
     $url = 'https://alpha.imeicheck.com/api/php-api/create?format='.$format.'&key='.$apiKey.'&service='.$service.'&imei='.$imei;
  
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

     $response = curl_exec ($ch);
     $err = curl_error($ch);  //if you need
     curl_close ($ch);
     return $response;
    }
```

html

```
<center>
    <form method="POST" action="" style="margin-top:5%">
        @csrf
        <p><input type="text" style="padding: 15px 10px 10px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',arial,sans-serif; border: 1px solid #cecece; color: black;box-sizing: border-box; width: 50%; max-width: 500px;" name="imei" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" placeholder="Write here IMEI or SN"></p>
        <select name="service" id="service" style="padding: 15px 10px 10px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',arial,sans-serif; border: 1px solid #cecece; color: black;box-sizing: border-box; width: 50%; max-width: 500px;">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">PLEASE CHOOSE CHECKER</option>
            <optgroup label="iPHONE SERVICES">
                <option value="0.01">Find My iPhone [ FMI ] (ON/OFF) &#x26A1;</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resultModal" type="submit" style="background-color: #2ABCA7; padding: 12px 45px; -ms-border-radius: 5px; -o-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid #2ABCA7;-webkit-transition: .5s; transition: .5s; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; width: 20%; max-width: 200px; color: #fff;">Submit</button>
    </form>

</center>


<div class="modal fade" id="resultModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="resultModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="resultModalLabel">Result</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form action method="post">
        @csrf
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="response">{{ old('$response') }}</textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">@lang('Close')</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

screen : https://i.ibb.co/H2GyFQ8/stylex.png

so i want get result in same page without get white page like in screenshot

and

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

use if `@if($response->name == 'test')  @endif`

Comment: @if($response->name == 'test')  @endif  using this in where sorry ,, mean where can i put this in modal or where ?

Comment: page blade laravel || or use if($response->name == 'test') php puer || only view

Comment: can you send me your facebook or something or talk and check again the code because i now editing it in controller

Comment: https://web.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100015861876023

Comment: Done Sending Add, Just Accept

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.